# how to convert Gregorian calendar to Coptic calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I need to add daily events to my website, according to the Coptic calendar.

How can I convert my Gregorian date to a Coptic date in PHP code to display the events of the day?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add more details, showing exactly what you're trying to do. At the moment it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: ^^ agreed -- please give some samples of the data, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found some PHP code here:

http://w3facility.org/question/get-today-coptic-date/

So you can use the `DateTime` class and convert it to a coptic date, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php